# Choosing the right game engine

Tags: java, 2d, android

I'm trying to create a game in java inspired by a Gameboy Color Zelda game. I'm exprienced in java but not in game programming. I've been doing a lot of research on game engines, and I'm currently considering JGame, GTGE, and Slick. Are these engines (or any that I have not seen) suited to a 2D game that entails a large environment and saved files? What engines would be suitable for this purpose?  On a side note, I'd also like to eventually make this game playable on Adroid, if that factors into which engine to choose.

Comment: It's a "down vote favorite" because it's off topic for the site. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) about what type of questions to ask here.

Comment: Questions like "What is the best for ...?" are like asking which laptop is best for game developer - this can't be answered everyone has it's own taste :) (I'm not downvoter :)

Answer (score 4):

There is crossplatform game engine - [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/).

I haven't tried it, but it seems to be engine you're looking for.

Comment: LibGDX is a great engine very fast, masks the use of OpenGL really well yet doesnt get in your way if you want to play with it. Also has library for handling UI and a implementation of Box2D theres more but I havent got that far yet :)

Comment: Yes, I like it very much, check out https://libgdx.info too